# Не могу заполнить таблицу SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

При попытке заполнить таблицу выдает следующую ошибку:

```
INSERT INTO Investors(InvestorName, PasportSN, PhoneNumber)
VALUES (`John McCallister`, `6705 1238`, `38-098-420-52-58`)
```

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'John McCallister' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался

```
INSERT INTO Investors(InvestorName,PasportSN,PhoneNumber)

VALUES ('John McCallister','6705 1276','38-092-420-52-58');
```

Написал вот так и заработало.